# Iterate through table and change td background color based on span value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs-directive

I have a `datatable` that values fetched from database,
I want to change td background color based on value in span.
Like if its **0** `td` color is *green*
else `td` color is *red*
[image]

This is my code for adding values in `td`

```
<td>
    <center>
        <span>CR303</span><br>
        <span ng-repeat="value in classrooms">
            <span ng-if="value.classroom_name=='CR303'">{{value.Schedules}}</span>
        </span>
    </center>
</td>
```

Comment: `Image` not enough, you should add your code.

Comment: I have added the code, please check

Comment: You tagged `jquery`, but your code is `angular` you wanna get this via `jquery` or `angular` ? which one?

Comment: via jquery, i want to iterate through table check its cell value and set the color of TD based on span value

Comment: @PoojaDhoot See the working fiddle link here, you just need to make the your requirement specific  changes there https://jsfiddle.net/Lr77dgmt/76/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to `iterate` `td` then get `span` text, now you can determine and use if condition.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $('td').each(function() {
    var val = $(this).find('.myval').text();
    if (val > 0) {
  $(this).removeClass("tdRed").addClass('tdGreen');
} else if(val == '0') {
    $(this).removeClass("tdGreen").addClass('tdRed');
} else if(val =='') {
    $(this).removeClass("tdGreen").removeClass('tdRed');
}
  });
}, 1000);
```

```css
.tdRed {
  color: red;
}

.tdGreen {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <center>
        <span>CR303</span><br>
        <span ng-repeat="value in classrooms">
<span ng-if="value.classroom_name=='CR303'" class="myval">0</span>
        </span>
      </center>
    </td>

    <td>
      <center>
        <span>CR304</span><br>
        <span ng-repeat="value in classrooms">
<span ng-if="value.classroom_name=='CR303'" class="myval">1</span>
        </span>
      </center>
    </td>

    <td>
      <center>
        <span>CR305</span><br>
        <span ng-repeat="value in classrooms">
<span ng-if="value.classroom_name=='CR303'" class="myval">22</span>
        </span>
      </center>
    </td>

    <td>
      <center>
        <span>CR306</span><br>
        <span ng-repeat="value in classrooms">
<span ng-if="value.classroom_name=='CR303'" class="myval">5</span>
        </span>
      </center>
    </td>

    <td>
      <center>
        <span>CR3011</span><br>
        <span ng-repeat="value in classrooms">
<span ng-if="value.classroom_name=='CR303'" >56</span>
        </span>
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is the function to be added on document load??

Comment: Wrap code with `$(document).ready(function(){ // code here // });` @PoojaDhoot

Comment: Its changing color of all td and document is loaded first before table could load

Comment: Just change `val == 0` to `val == '0'` it will fix the color issue. You must render this code after table created. @PoojaDhoot

Comment: then it gives color red,

Comment: Actulaay the vlaue i am getting in $val is undefined, its not fetching span values

Comment: You want this, didn't you? `if its 0 td color is green else td color is red ` @PoojaDhoot Did you add class to td ? probably you run this code before value create. I recommend you to this via `angularjs` not `jquery`

Comment: I have added the class, but still the td values are red as the else condition is getting true

Comment: You made me confuse. You want if value equal to `0` make td green, else red. am i wrong? now you can change the condition as you want.

Comment: change the value? last time i check, you didn't ask about changing value. For end of the story, once again, do clarify, explain brightly what you want, from zero to hundred.

Comment: By changing the values i meant var val is undefined, its not fetching table cell span values

Comment: How you changing value? on page refresh? on click? on input? on what? you should explain more.

Comment: On page load, angular js function is called, from which values are passed to $scope variable and that scope variable is used in td ng-repeat to get values of td, later on date change again that function is called

Comment: Let us test something. See my updated answer. Try the code with `setInterval`

Comment: do i need to add that on document load?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module("Profile", []);
app.controller("ProfileCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.JSON_value = [
    [{
      'classroom_name': 'CR303',
      'Schedules': 0
    }, {
      'classroom_name': 'CR303',
      'Schedules': 1
    }, {
      'classroom_name': 'CR303',
      'Schedules': 2
    }],
    [{
      'classroom_name': 'CR303',
      'Schedules': 1
    }, {
      'classroom_name': 'CR303',
      'Schedules': 1
    }, {
      'classroom_name': 'CR303',
      'Schedules': 2
    }],
    [{
      'classroom_name': 'CR303',
      'Schedules': 1
    }, {
      'classroom_name': 'CR303',
      'Schedules': 1
    }, {
      'classroom_name': 'CR303',
      'Schedules': 2
    }],
    [{
      'classroom_name': 'CR303',
      'Schedules': 0
    }, {
      'classroom_name': 'CR303',
      'Schedules': 1
    }, {
      'classroom_name': 'CR303',
      'Schedules': 2
    }],
    [{
      'classroom_name': 'CR303',
      'Schedules': 0
    }, {
      'classroom_name': 'CR303',
      'Schedules': 1
    }, {
      'classroom_name': 'CR303',
      'Schedules': 2
    }],
    [{
      'classroom_name': 'CR303',
      'Schedules': 1
    }, {
      'classroom_name': 'CR303',
      'Schedules': 1
    }, {
      'classroom_name': 'CR303',
      'Schedules': 2
    }]
  ]
})
```

```css
table tbody tr td.Color_red {
  color: red;
}

table tbody tr td.Color_green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="Profile" ng-controller="ProfileCtrl">
  <table class="table" border="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="classrooms in  JSON_value track by $index" ng-class="{'Color_red': classrooms[0]['Schedules'] !=  0 ,'Color_green':classrooms[0]['Schedules'] ==  0}">
          <span>CR303</span><br>
          <span ng-repeat="value in classrooms track by $index">
                                                        <span ng-if="value.classroom_name=='CR303'">{{value.Schedules}}</span>
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Use Angularjs ng-class="{'Color_red': classrooms[0]['Schedules'] !=  0 ,'Color_green':classrooms[0]['Schedules'] ==  0}"

Comment: the classrooms value is fetched from controller through model. and there are 35 result set

Comment: is possible can u share your sample datastructure for td values and classrooms values?are you  using ng-repeat inside ng-repeat?

Comment: Thank you for yours time, got the result with above code